# Impact on EWS managed APIs with update of Calendar sharing in Office 365

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices

My partner provides their own calendar service with using [EWS managed APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641956(v=exchg.150).aspx) to pull the Office 365 calendar data in order to display the result in their own calendear application.

Reading the article for [Calendar sharing in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calendar-sharing-in-Office-365-b576ecc3-0945-4d75-85f1-5efafb8a37b4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), it explained about the third party client as "We do not support the shared calendar improvements for EWS-based clients, so you will not see your shared calendars in any calendar application that uses EWS, such as Mac OS X."

## Question to ask the community;

-Does this mean that currently running EWS managed APIs will not be feasible any more after the update of Calendar sharing in Office 365 is fully implemented?

or

-This just explains that EWS managed APIs does not simply cover (or support) update part of Calendar sharing in Office 365, and they can still use the current EWS managed APIs?

I sincerely appreciate for your gentle feedback.
Thannk you, Tommy

Answer (score 0):

> > Does this mean that currently running EWS managed APIs will not be feasible any more after the update of Calendar sharing in Office 365 is fully implemented?

No its not a breaking change its an enhancement eg just another new feature, it is however not going to be available if your using EWS to access mailboxes (which is consistent to the messaging Microsoft has given about new features not being included in EWS). It shouldn't affect the conventional EWS API access to a Mailbox calendar.  Long term they should still be looking to move away from EWS as that will give them the ability to capture new features and changes in the future as the platform continues to evolve.

Comment: I really appreciate your gentle support to give me feedback, and I understood that the update of office 365 calendar sharing might not affect on EWS API access, though we still need to pay attention in further updates. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I try to add a delegate calendar on Apple Calendar for macOS I get the following:
[image]

The calendar of the same user is visible from Office 365 web portal. Is this caused by lack of support on EWS?